# VSTest.Console.exe Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I'm trying to set up a C# project with the latest version of Visual Studio, 2022; this is with .Net 6 on Windows 10. It's a simple console program, and I've set up the project and a corresponding unit test project basically following the steps described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022 so I've got something isomorphic to that tutorial project.

And the unit tests work fine when run from within Visual Studio.

Now I want to also run them from the command line.

`vstest.console bin\Debug\net6.0\foo.dll`

gives

> Testhost process exited with error: Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
> . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Looks like the toolchain is failing to find one of its own libraries? Is there some option I need to be specifying?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After upgrading from .Net 5 to .Net 6, I had to face the same issue.

Add the following two lines to your .csproj file to fix the issue.

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>false</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
<GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigDevFile>
```

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you chose the Correct Assembly which contain the tests and reference `MSTest.TestFramework` if you follow convention naming, Then Name should be look like `FooTests.dll`

in the [example you mention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022) the following line will throw error

```
vstest.console ..\BankTests\bin\Debug\net6.0\Bank.dll
```

While this will run normally

```
vstest.console ..\BankTests\bin\Debug\net6.0\BankTests.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from .NET5 to .NET6 I had the same issue. The solution that worked for me was removing the flag `UseCommonOutputDirectory` from the test .csproj file.

Then I found this issue that explains why it happened:
[UseCommonOutputDirectory=true breaks dotnet test #27320](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27320)

Answer (score 0):

It's a round-about way Visual Studio tells you to use `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` NuGet in your project with tests.