# MStest doesn't execute unit tests when OutputPath of the project changes

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2022

When I change the `OutputPath` for my unit test project the tests are still discoverable in `Test Explorer`, but when I try to run them (right-click -> Run) they don't run and I get the error below in Output window. Why it suddenly doesn't find that dll?

```
Building Test Projects
Starting test discovery for requested test run
========== Starting test discovery ==========
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process exited with error: Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.ThrowOnTestHostExited(Boolean testHostExited)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 859.1 ms ==========
========== Starting test run ==========
========== Test run finished: 0 Tests (0 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in < 1 ms ==========
```

The `bin` folder in the new `OutputPath` location seems to have all files that would have been in the `bin` folder inside the project folder if I haven't changed the `OutputPath`.

I use MStest from Visual Studio 2022.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76718122/3817408 seems to indicate that the UseCommonOutputDirectory flag may be causing this issue.